# UIImageView with black edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with an image, however, the image seems to be shifted with one edge being black

[image]

What's even stranger is that the edge is either side or top at what-seems-to-be random

[image]

The `UIButton` has been added via Interface Builder, and I have set the content mode to `Aspect Fill`. Also, in code, I have set the following:

```
self.itemImage.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Any ideas what could be the reason? Also worth noting that this happens only on a device (iPhone 6, iOS8.4). On a simulator there are no black edges, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the background color to see if the black edges we see is the background.

```
self.itemImage.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

If the edges didn't become yellow, then it might be the images that cause the problem.

Comment: Hi @Boris88, I tried your suggestion, but the edge stays black, i.e. it doesn't seem to be the background color showing,

Comment: Boris, thanks for helping me rule out an area the issue was not originating from. As per your suggestion, I looked at the source images, and they are indeed already with those black areas. I will have to now find an issues in my image resizing / cropping code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

> self.itemImage.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

Comment: This does get rid of the black edges, however, the images are not scaled down to aspect-fill the imageView. How could I achieve both?